# Pre-Scaling and Supporting Different Size Screens Android

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

I am reading through http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and trying to understand how pre-scaling works.

I have the following layout file which is optimized for the galaxy tab :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayoutmain"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainmenu"
>
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/start_button"
android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"
android:layout_marginTop ="70dip"
android:layout_width="500dip"
android:layout_height="214dip"
android:background="@drawable/startsession"
android:contentDescription="@string/descbuttonstart"
/>
```

I have placed the images for the screen in the drawable-ldpi folder. The problem is that when I test the app on a smaller screen (using the emulator) the screen does not scale properly - the button is massive and not positioned correctly.

Is it possible to just have one layout file for all screens and if so what is the secret to getting this working ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO , AFAIK its not possible you need to have  three differents folders(hdpi,mdpi,ldpi)  with different dimensions for buttons,images etc
and also for layout again you need to have three layout folders (layout-small,layout-medium,layout-large)

Answer (score 0):

Screen size and screen resolution are two independent things. the resources in ldpi folder are for low resolution and not necessory small screen sizes. The way I prefer is to define resources for high resolution and let them scale down on others.

Comment: Thanks - so I should design a separate layout file for each screen size ?